# ethernet connection not showing in top menubar in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

I am on ubuntu 14.04(in dual boot with 16.04). I am connected to a router. when I try to connect to ethernet using the network connections in top menubar, I can't find the connection listed. only auto-ethernot shows in the list. However if I click the "edit connections" I can see the required connection. This doesn't seem to be a router problem or a lan card problem as I can connect to the ethernet when I boot into ubuntu 16.04.

Another **IMPORTANT** information is that I had cloned the hard disk from ubuntu installation in a different machine into this machine.

I list below some basic tests I ran:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 04
       serial: 4c:72:b9:31:ea:0c
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=half firmware=0.13-5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 memory:f7100000-f711ffff memory:f7138000-f7138fff ioport:f020(size=32)



lspci | grep Ethernet
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)



ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:72:b9:31:ea:0c  
          inet6 addr: fe80::4e72:b9ff:fe31:ea0c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2658571 errors:7 dropped:3918 overruns:0 frame:7
          TX packets:798405 errors:115 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:115
          collisions:357614 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1952910470 (1.9 GB)  TX bytes:73398243 (73.3 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7100000-f7120000



cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN


ls -la /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Dec 13  2012 /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal command.

Comment: its there. i have added it already.  adding it once more here:cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback